# How to use Thread.sleep in a loop within NetBeans SWING?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, netbeans, sleep

I am making a cosmetic SWING GUI program, in NetBeans, just for some fun with friends and it involves a loading screen that really only takes a few milliseconds but I want it to take a few seconds to finish, which is where I am trying to use the Thread.sleep() . The loading is a For-Loop and I know you have to throw InterruptedException but being that it is made with the NetBeans GUI builder you can't add it, I have tried just copy and pasted into a different project but it just comes up with errors. So my question is how I would get the Thread.sleep() to work or if there is some alternative way of causing the program to pause. Thank you

Edit: Basically... How do I get a loop to pause every interval so that five loop intervals take five seconds.

Comment: That's the problem with GUI builders. If you use them, you have to play with their rules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is really difficult to understand; I'm not sure what problem you're trying to explain. You'll get better answers if you include the code you have now and are concise and precise about what problems you're having.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** use `Thread.sleep()` in Swing GUI application. Alternatively use [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for the same behavior.

Please have a look about [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Read more about [Thread.Sleep alternative in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700571/thread-sleep-alternative-in-java)

---

> You can use Swing timers in two ways:

- To perform a task once, after a delay.

  For example, the tool tip manager uses Swing timers to determine when to show a tool tip and when to hide it.
- To perform a task repeatedly.

  For example, you might perform animation or update a component that displays progress toward a goal.