# Lag spike when moving player

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

The player is a panel, and it is getting removed, its position changed, and then re-added to another panel (which is what contains this method) which is drawn to the main frame. There are also a lot of other small panels containing a grass sprite being drawn to the primary panel as terrain tiles. I think the problem is that when I call `revalidate()`, it revalidates all those little panels as well. How can I solve this?

EDIT: I should mention that I am using `RelativeLayout` to position the players on the primary panel.

```
private class MainKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(AttentionedPlayer != null)
        {
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                AttentionedPlayer.Ypos -= 16;
            }
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                AttentionedPlayer.Ypos += 16;
            }
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                AttentionedPlayer.Xpos -= 16;
            }
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                AttentionedPlayer.Xpos += 16;
            }
            remove(AttentionedPlayer);
            AttentionedPlayer.movePlayer();
            System.out.println("!!!!"+AttentionedPlayer.constraints.toString());
            add(AttentionedPlayer, AttentionedPlayer.constraints, AttentionedPlayer.Zpos);
            AttentionedPlayer.revalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you *revalidating*? are you removing/adding components from the panels or frame? if not there is no need for it. BTW I would suggest use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing as `KeyListener` is AWT and has focus isssues

Comment: also you should not repaint the whole panel if only a small part changes. calculate what changes and use repaint(Rectangle r)

Comment: After your edit, in gaming I tend not to use Layouts, this is the few times where absolute positioning is best (Im talking about in the actual panel which draws the game).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AttentionedPlayer.movePlayer();` seems to be an intensive operation, and you execute it from within [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) (the GUI thread). Instead, execute it from within a new thread or a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546203/597657) to know more about [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Comment: @DavidKroukamp That's the only non-swing-related method I can see that could cause some lag :)

Comment: Now I get it.. +1. Though OP should also not really be using `revalidate()` if he has many panels this call will take long too

Comment: So to use SwingWorker, I essentially make a class that extends SwingWorker, override it doInBackground() function, and then just make it do whatever I want?

Comment: @sunnydan Yes, and then invoke `swingworkerinstance.execute()` inside `keyPressed()`.

Answer (score 3):

@Eng.Fouad had a good point +1 to him, though I personally have never needed this for that exact reason, but your move method might be very cpu intensive.

Just to show an example (expanding from my comments) using your *`JPanel` game logic*, if implemented *correctly* there would be no need for `revalidate()` on player move (via `setLocation(..)`) which IMO is what also could cause a great amount of lag especially if there are many components. As you will see my `GamePanel` extends `JPanel` and uses `Null`/`Absolute` Layout (but for good reason in gaming we want more control over the Layout).

Also used `KeyBinding`s to show you their useage.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GameLogic {

    public GameLogic() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Entity entity = new Entity("Player", 100, 100, 50, 50);//starting location 100,100 and width/height 50x50

        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(300, 300);
        gp.addEntity(entity);

        setGamePanelKeyBindings(gp, entity);

        frame.add(gp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setGamePanelKeyBindings(GamePanel gp, final Entity entity) {
        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "D pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("D pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.move(Entity.RIGHT);
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "A pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("A pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.move(Entity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "W pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("W pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.move(Entity.UP);
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "S pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("S pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.move(Entity.DOWN);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameLogic();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Entity extends JPanel {

    private int width = 50, height = 50;
    private int speed = 5;
    public static final int UP = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3, RIGHT = 4;

    public Entity(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        add(new JLabel(text));
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void move(int direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case UP:
                setLocation(getX(), getY() - speed);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                setLocation(getX(), getY() + speed);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                setLocation(getX() - speed, getY());
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                setLocation(getX() + speed, getY());
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        grphcs.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private int width, height;

    GamePanel(int w, int h) {
        setLayout(null);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity e) {
        add(e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        grphcs.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Sorry I couldn't stop myself

if you are interested here is a bit of an advanced version with gameloop that can be paused, frame rate etc can be set, 2 keys (like <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>  may be pressed simultaneously thus causing `JPanel` to move diagonally):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GameLogic {

    public GameLogic() {
        initComponents();
    }
    final GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(500, 500);

    private void initComponents() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Entity entity = new Entity("Player", 100, 100, 100, 100);

        gp.addEntity(entity);

        setGamePanelKeyBindings(gp, entity);

        frame.add(gp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //start the game loop which will repaint the screen
        runGameLoop();
    }
    //Starts a new thread and runs the game loop in it.

    public void runGameLoop() {
        Thread loop = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gp.running = true;
                gp.gameLoop();
            }
        });
        loop.start();
    }

    private void setGamePanelKeyBindings(GamePanel gp, final Entity entity) {
        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "D pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("D pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.RIGHT = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "A pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("A pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.LEFT = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "W pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("W pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.UP = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "S pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("S pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.DOWN = true;
            }
        });
        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "D released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("D released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.RIGHT = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "A released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("A released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.LEFT = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "W released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("W released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.UP = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "S released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("S released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.DOWN = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameLogic();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Entity extends JPanel {

    private int width = 50, height = 50;
    private int speed = 5;
    public boolean UP = false, DOWN = false, LEFT = false, RIGHT = false;

    public Entity(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        add(new JLabel(text));
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void move() {
        if (UP) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() - speed);
        }
        if (DOWN) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() + speed);
        }
        if (LEFT) {
            setLocation(getX() - speed, getY());
        }
        if (RIGHT) {
            setLocation(getX() + speed, getY());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        grphcs.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private int width, height;
    private int frameCount = 0;
    private int fps = 0;
    public static boolean running = false, paused = false;
    final ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    GamePanel(int w, int h) {
        setLayout(null);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity e) {
        add(e);
        entities.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);

        grphcs.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        grphcs.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        grphcs.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 5, 10);

        frameCount++;
    }

    //Only run this in another Thread!
    public void gameLoop() {
        //This value would probably be stored elsewhere.
        final double GAME_HERTZ = 30.0;
        //Calculate how many ns each frame should take for our target game hertz.
        final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
        //At the very most we will update the game this many times before a new render.
        //If you're worried about visual hitches more than perfect timing, set this to 1.
        final int MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER = 5;
        //We will need the last update time.
        double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Store the last time we rendered.
        double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

        //If we are able to get as high as this FPS, don't render again.
        final double TARGET_FPS = 60;
        final double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

        //Simple way of finding FPS.
        int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

        while (running) {
            double now = System.nanoTime();
            int updateCount = 0;

            if (!paused) {
                //Do as many game updates as we need to, potentially playing catchup.
                while (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER) {
                    updateGame();
                    lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                    updateCount++;
                }

                //If for some reason an update takes forever, we don't want to do an insane number of catchups.
                //If you were doing some sort of game that needed to keep EXACT time, you would get rid of this.
                if (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                }

                drawGame();
                lastRenderTime = now;

                //Update the frames we got.
                int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
                if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime) {
                    System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount);
                    fps = frameCount;
                    frameCount = 0;
                    lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
                }

                //Yield until it has been at least the target time between renders. This saves the CPU from hogging.
                while (now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    //allow the threading system to play threads that are waiting to run.
                    Thread.yield();

                    //This stops the app from consuming all your CPU. It makes this slightly less accurate, but is worth it.
                    //You can remove this line and it will still work (better), your CPU just climbs on certain OSes.
                    //FYI on some OS's this can cause pretty bad stuttering. Scroll down and have a look at different peoples' solutions to this.
                    //On my OS it does not unpuase the game if i take this away
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    now = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGame() {
        for (Entity e : entities) {
            e.move();
        }
    }

    private void drawGame() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```