# Paint from different classes

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make a game in Java (school project) and I have the following setup:

A main class, extended with JFrame, a 'Game' class, extended with JPanel.

Now from within this main class, I make calls to a class 'Player' and a class 'Map'.. The class 'Map' exists of two subclasses 'Blocks' and 'Bombs'.

But I'm wondering.. How do I let the paint methods of all this classes paint to the same JPanel (of the class Game)?

I gave every class the method 'public void paint(Graphics g)' and do the painting.. But only the painting of the class 'Game' shows up when i run the program, not the painting from the subclasses.

How do I implement this?

By example, I reduced my code to this:

Main class:

```
    BomberGame game = new BomberGame();
        add(game);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setTitle("Bomber");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BomberB1 main = new BomberB1();
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
    package bomberb1;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class BomberGame extends JPanel {
    public BomberGame() {;
        BomberMap map = new BomberMap(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Map class:

```
    package bomberb1;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class BomberMap{
    BomberGame game;
    public BomberMap(BomberGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(30, 30, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: _How do I let the paint methods of all this classes paint to the same JPanel_ You don't! This is really the worst design you can choose. You are mixing models and views (see also MVC pattern). You should rather create differents views and nest those panels inside each other. This is the purpose of having a graphical hierarchy (each child paints a subregion of its parent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Entity class (which could be Map player etc) to be drawn have a `draw` method that accepts a `Graphics` object thus allowing it to access the `Graphics` object of the `JPanel` and draw to it, something like:

```
class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    Entity e=new Entity;

    @Override
    protected paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        e.draw(g);//call draw method for entity and pass graphics object
    }

}

class Entity {

   //will draw whats necessary to Graphics object
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        //draw to the graphics object here
    }
}
```

Other suggestions:

- Do not extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily
- override `JPanel` `paintComponent()` and not `paint()` (+1 to trashGod comment)
- Swing components should be created and manipulated on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` block.

**UPDATE:**

As @GuillaumePolet stated a better game design would be implementing `JPanel`s as parent class for most of the game entities see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791614/lag-spike-when-moving-player/13792012#13792012) similar answer for more.

Comment: IMO, Entity should also be a JComponent and override `paintComponent` and should be a child of GamePanel.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 I guess that would depend on OPs choice of game design, but yes that would be an option.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  Or 'paint in an image' as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13796268/418556).  I only tend to extend components for custom painting these days when I intend to put components over the top of it (very, very rare) or need 1000 FPS(?) performance (but that is looking like 'Full-screen exclusive mode' all the way).