# Java doesn't like downloading files.

Tags: java, swing, download

I'm creating a Swing GUI that will have multiple features for updating. If a user is not properly updated, it will display a "Download & Install" button. That works fine, but pressing the button does nothing. It doesn't freeze, it just sort of sits there. Nonetheless, "setup.exe" is a pretty large file (~600MB), but it doesn't show me anything nor does the file even begin to appear in the C:\ directory. What am I doing wrong here?

```
protected static JButton aroundTheLake; 

private static JButton aroundTheRiver() {
    aroundTheLake = new JButton("DOWNLOAD & INSTALL!");
    aroundTheLake.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    aroundTheLake.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING); //aka LEFT, for left-to-right locales
    aroundTheLake.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    aroundTheLake.setActionCommand("aroundthelake");
    return aroundTheLake;
}

private static String readURL(String targetURL) {
    String returnish = "";
    try {
        URL tempURL = new URL(targetURL); 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(tempURL.openStream()); 
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            returnish = returnish+s.nextLine(); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
    return returnish;
}

private static String readFile(String targetFile) { 
    String returnString = "";
    try {
        File tempFile = new File(targetFile);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(tempFile);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            returnString = returnString + s.nextLine(); 
        }
    } catch(IOException e) { 
        // !
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return returnString;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("aroundthelake".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        try { 
                System.out.println("initiated");
                URL website = new URL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/setup.exe");
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("setup.exe");
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
        } catch (IOException exc) { 
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    } else {
        // man
    }
}

private static void showGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xA64343));

    File fileCheck = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)");
    String returnString = null;
    String rootDirectory = null;
    if (fileCheck.exists()) {
        rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files (x86)/DreamWorks Interactive"; 
        String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
        File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            returnString = readFile(checkFile);
        } else {
            returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version."; 
        }
    } else {
        rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files/DreamWorks Interactive";
        String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
        File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            returnString = readFile(checkFile);
        } else {
            returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version.";
        }
    }
    if (returnString.equals(readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/version.txt"))) {
        returnString = "You are updated to the recent version!"; 
    } else { 
        returnString = "It appears you're not updated.";
    }

    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
    headerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel heapPanel = new JPanel();
    heapPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(heapPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    heapPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, heapPanel.getPreferredSize().height));
    JTextArea heapLabel = new JTextArea(50, 50);        
    heapLabel.setLineWrap(true);
    heapLabel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    heapLabel.setEditable(false);
    heapLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
    heapLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    heapLabel.append("Current version: "+readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/prettyversion.txt")+".\nInstalled version: "+readFile(rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/prettyversion.txt")+".\n"+returnString+"\n" + 
        "You can read the full version of the document to the left at http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net."
        + "\nHaven't installed yet? Below is the download button. Just click to save setup.exe in and enjoy!");
    heapPanel.add(heapLabel);
    if (returnString == "It appears you're not updated.") { 
        heapPanel.add(aroundTheRiver());
    }

    try {
        Font sFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DUGFB___.TTF"));
        sFont = sFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 48);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(sFont);
        headerLabel.setFont(sFont);
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    BufferedImage icoImage = null;
    try {
        icoImage = ImageIO.read(
            frame.getClass().getResource("/nhood.bmp"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    frame.setIconImage(icoImage);

    JEditorPane updateLog = new JEditorPane();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(updateLog);
    updateLog.setEditable(false);

    try {
        updateLog.setPage("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        updateLog.setContentType("text/html");
        updateLog.setText("<html>The application could not load the webpage.</html>");
    }

    frame.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.add(heapPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you add an `ActionListener` to your button (or an `Action`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user interface freezes because you are keeping the event dispatch thread busy for download.

The event dispatch thread is the same thread that maintains the UI "alive" - you should **never** do anything that takes a perceivably long time directly in an event handler.

What you should do instead is launch a separate thread that downloads the file. To make this user friendly you can use a [progress monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#monitors) so that the user sees what your program is doing, and ideally how long it is going to take. I recommend going through the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to see how that is done.

A quick solution is just launching a new thread. This is not very user friendly though, since there will be absolutely no user feedback.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("aroundthelake".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try { 
                    System.out.println("initiated");
                    URL website = new URL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/setup.exe"); 
                    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("setup.exe");
                    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                } catch (IOException exc) { 
                    System.out.println(exc);
                }   
            }   
        }.start();

    } else {
        // man
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two main issues within your code:

- You haven't registered the action listener to your button. Do it like this:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

- `actionPerformed()` is executed on the GUI-thread ([EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)), so avoid executing intensive operations on it. Instead use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). See [How SwingWorker works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546203/597657).

Comment: Yes, yes. I actually kind of looked down upon myself for not adding an ActionListener. But the output is now giving me `UpdateMechanism.java:39: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. I should probably fix that before moving on.

Comment: @cygorx remove `this`, and use an instance of a class that implements ActionListener, or create it as an anonymous-class.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1) **NEVER** make network calls from the Swing thread!  Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).  When the Swing EDT is blocked all UI action ceases. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more info.

2) You really don't need to override JButton.  Just add an ActionListener instead.  You're making your code less flexible this way.

3) Make sure you actually call [addActionListener()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29).