# How to set loading image on swing when request takes few times to get response?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I am making an application on swing. When I tried to fetch record from database which has more than thousands rows. It takes few time to retrieve. It may make bored to my client. So I want to display **message** like

```
Loading please wait...
```

If request takes more than 5 minutes to get response at any request I want to display like above message.
Please help me..
Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16938228/1057230) by @MadProgrammer, this might can give a slight idea how to go about achieving what you so desire :-)

Comment: OK.I will try to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look through [Concurrency In Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)...

Probably the easiest solution would be use a `SwingWorker`, which will allow to execute the request in a background thread, but provides a number of methods to sync the updates back to the UI.

For example...

```
SwingWorker requestWorker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception{
        // Make your request
        // Process your request
        // You can use setProgress if you know how many values you have...
        // (You will need to use a property listener to monitor
        //  these changes ;))
        // You can also use publish to push updates back to the UI
        return null;
    }

    protected void done() {
        // Remove the "wait" notification...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `JXBusyLabel` in `JavaFX`. Simply paint the label over glasspane. This [link](http://www.jroller.com/Thierry/entry/swingx_glasspaneworker_lock_the_glasspane) might help you.

Comment: Thanks Ghanesh ji... I will check